# Share folder inside a main folder without accessing main folder

Tags: permissions, ntfs, network-shares

I have local share folder "Share" in my D: disk. Like this: \Share\Marketing

I want to give marketing access to Marketing folder but they must not have access to Share folder.

I gave them NTFS read permissions to only marketing folder and when I go to that location by IP address I can see whole share. which I do not want.

When I got by computer name, I can't access neither Marketing and Share.

I'm not very good at permissions so I need help.

Comment: Can you block access to the whole Share folder to that user but allow access to the Marketing folder only, perhaps?

Comment: I have not seen this capability. We separate root folders by user access to avoid this issue. People see applicable root folders and the folders below and that works well

Comment: Give access to only Marketing folder, disable permission inheritance so other folders do not inherit the same permissions, and you can enable enumeration. 

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/enable-access-based-enumeration-on-a-namespace

Comment: Remove any NTFS permissions for them from D:\Share, add them to D:\Share\Marketing folder. They *should* only be able to access \\sharename\Marketing (and sub-folders if inheritance is on). Enumeration only hides subfolders that they cannot access, while in a folder they can access. (Obviously make sure the share permissions are as permissive as they need to be in any location within the share)

Comment: @kamil234, how can I disable permission inheritance, maybe from advance permission menu? can you explain shortly?